# C# XNA VertexBuffer fail to render texture

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying make 3D XNA game, but when I try load my model, it fails to render texture and lightining dosent really work, looks mostly just black, but model shape is right.

Looks in-game:

[image: Screenshot]

Should look:

[image: Screenshot]

Code:

```
class Floor
{
    private int floorWidth;
    private int floorHeight;
    private VertexBuffer floorBuffer;
    private IndexBuffer indexBuffer;
    private GraphicsDevice device;

    public Floor(GraphicsDevice device, int width, int height)
    {
        this.device = device;
        this.floorWidth = width;
        this.floorHeight = height;

        BuildFloorBuffer();
    }

    private void BuildFloorBuffer()
    {
        List<short> indexList = new List<short>();
        List<VertexPositionNormalTexture> vertexList = new List<VertexPositionNormalTexture>();

        foreach (ModelMesh mesh in Game1.myModel.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (ModelMeshPart part in mesh.MeshParts)
            {
                VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vertexArray = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[part.VertexBuffer.VertexCount];
                part.VertexBuffer.GetData<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(vertexArray);
                vertexList.AddRange(vertexArray.ToList());

                short[] indexArray = new short[part.IndexBuffer.IndexCount];
                part.IndexBuffer.GetData<short>(indexArray);
                indexList.AddRange(indexArray);
            }
        }

        floorBuffer = new VertexBuffer(device, VertexPositionNormalTexture.VertexDeclaration, vertexList.Count, BufferUsage.None);
        floorBuffer.SetData<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(vertexList.ToArray());

        indexBuffer = new IndexBuffer(device, IndexElementSize.SixteenBits, sizeof(short) * indexList.Count, BufferUsage.None);
        indexBuffer.SetData<short>(indexList.ToArray());
    }

    public void Draw(Camera camera,  BasicEffect effect)
    {
        effect.VertexColorEnabled = false;
        effect.TextureEnabled = true;
        effect.LightingEnabled = true;

        effect.View = camera.View;
        effect.Projection = camera.Projection;
        effect.World = Matrix.Identity;

        effect.EnableDefaultLighting();

        foreach(EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();

            device.Indices = indexBuffer;
            device.SetVertexBuffer(floorBuffer);
            device.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0, floorBuffer.VertexCount, 0, floorBuffer.VertexCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you let the Mesh draw itself? There might be an index buffer, which you are ignoring.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Because I got camera and it dosen't work correctly, stays on screen allways. Index buffer? Where do I need that?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a sensible reason. The index buffer is a member of the `ModelMeshPart`. You should set it on the device like the vertex buffer. Merging all buffers into one requires a bit of attention because the indices are shifted. Therefore, I strongly recommend using the built-in functionalities of `ModelMesh`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler It just simply dont work how I want it works. Added IndexBuffer, nothing changed.

Comment: You need [`DrawIndexedPrimitives`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.graphicsdevice.drawindexedprimitives.aspx) then.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Works little bit beter, just two sides without lightining :s